# Obsidian.md Plugins: ''obsidian' not defined'

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-5, obsidian

I am currently writing a plugin for obsidian.md that renders math functions inside a code block. I used webpack for bundling node libraries like yaml and function-plot. In the config, I added 'obsidian' as an external. The plugin builds with a warning about the bundle size but that doesn't matter since it's local anyways. When I add the plugin, it always says ''obsidian' not defined'. I guess it's looking for obsidian in the global context and can't find it? Here's the repo: https://github.com/leonhma/obsidian-functionplot
Do you know how to configure webpack properly? There's probably some really easy fix but I'm also new to typescript, webpack and developing plugins for obsidian..

Comment: Where exactly does the Error get thrown? Could you add some Logs. Also, when you add the library where exactly? Some Snippets or Steps to reproduce would be nice.

Comment: I am not familiar with webpack, but maybe you could get some ideas by looking at other plugins that use webpack? See for example  https://github.com/hadynz/obsidian-kindle-plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @håkon-hægland for your suggestion (why didn't I think of that?). First of all, the file generated by webpack looked like

```js
function(obsidian) {
... (around 300kb code)
}(obsidian);
```

, so webpack tried to access some global object called 'obsidian'. The important part in `webpack.config.js` was

```js
...
externals: [
    obsidian: 'obsidian'
],
...
```

As per your suggestion, i took a look at the other repo, and they use

```js
...
externals: [
    obsidian: 'commonjs2 obsidian'
],
...
```

That fixed my problem and now obsidian is properly imported at runtime. Just posting this in case someone else has this problem, as i couldn't find an existing answer myself.

PS: For those interested, since you are most certainly developing obsidian plugins: It was also really important to set `output.libraryTarget` to `commonjs` or `commonjs2` inside the webpack config.